# git in a git subdirectory with gitignore

Tags: git

My question **was**: How to make a git repo in a subdirectory of my current git repo.

My solution: I just ignored the subfolder in my `gitignore`. Went to that subfolder and created a new repo.

My question **now**: Is this wrong?

Comment: Do you WANT the parent git repository to keep track of the git repository in the subdirectory? For example, do you want your parent git repository to keep track of the commit on the subdirectory's repo (using something like submodules)? Or do you just want to have two git directories in this directory structure, but not actually track how the two relate? The problem is that both ways are right, but what problem you're trying to solve might give rise to why one way might be better than another.

Comment: It might be better to have it in my own repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I believe this is wrong ; )

Gitignoring and nesting like this will only lead to confusion, since the "parent" repo has no knowledge of changes that have gone on in the "child" repo, and you will have to remember to change your working directory to the "child" every time you want to track a change. Also, if others are collaborating on the project, they will have to manually clone the second repository down (which gets messier as you add collaborators).

You should be using git [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). This would allow you to include a separate repository without the side effects from a repo within a repo. Submodules have their own set of quirks, but they are the cleanest most `git` like way to do things ^^

That said, what is the reason for wanting to "nest" repositories like this?

Comment: I'm working with a team that not all of them uses git. So for some parts I download X work in a subdirectory. I make some changes to it. X updates his work and send it to me. Here I want to update my subdirectory and merge my own changes to. So that's where my idea came from :)